# How to get gradle test case console output

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle to manager my project and I use gradle test --tests XXXX command to run a single test class. I wander where I can find the console output of my test cases. I know that there is a directory test-results under build which has all test cases result. But it only has the results when the test case finished. If my case is running hours and I want to monitor the output, where I can find them?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Test.onOutput](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:onOutput%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
  onOutput {
       descriptor, event 
    -> if( event.destination == TestOutputEvent.Destination.StdErr ) {
         logger.error(   "Test: " 
                       + descriptor 
                       + ", error: "
                       + event.message)
} } }
```

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't work. It seems this configuration doesn't have any impact on the test output.